# Elliptic curve is to Tate module as genus one curve is to blank?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$, and let $\rho:\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_\ell)$ be its Tate module.

Let $T$ be the set of isomorphism classes of $E$-torsors.  Is there a good way to describe this set in group-theoretic/representation-theoretic terms, just using $\rho$?

Comment: What is the answer to the corresponding question for the multiplicative group ?